Changing the amount of time a closed banner will appear again via this script
Here is the script I have which allows the user to close a floating text banner that appears at the top of the page and it works as intended.
<script>!function(){let e=document.getElementById("top-ad-bar"),t=localStorage.getItem("topAdBarClosedAt"),l=new Date().getTime();(!t||l-t>=9e5)&&(e.style.display="flex")}();
</script>

However the banner returns if the page is reloaded after about 30 minutes.  Can someone tell me how (!t||l-t>=9e5) translates to any amount of time and how to increase to say 3 hours?

The condition (!t || l - t >= 9e5) in your script is checking whether the banner should be shown based on the following logic:
t: The timestamp when the user last closed the banner (stored in localStorage).
l: The current timestamp (the moment the script runs, using new Date().getTime()).
9e5 is shorthand for 900,000 milliseconds, which equals 15 minutes (since 1 minute = 60,000 milliseconds).
The condition l - t >= 9e5 checks whether at least 15 minutes (900,000 milliseconds) have passed since the banner was last closed. If this is true, the banner will be displayed again. If the user has never closed the banner, t will be null, and the banner will be displayed.
To change the timeout to 3 hours, you need to update the value 9e5 to the number of milliseconds in 3 hours.
1 hour = 60 minutes = 60 * 60 = 3600 seconds = 3,600,000 milliseconds.
3 hours = 3 * 3,600,000 milliseconds = 10,800,000 milliseconds.
So, replace 9e5 with 1.08e7 (which is 10,800,000 milliseconds).
Once replaced, the banner will only reappear if 3 hours have passed since the user last closed it.

Wow that was awesome, thanks for the clear help and explanation.  So 2.16e7 would be 6 hours?  I was going to try to determine it myself but I'm glad I didn't try - a millisecond to hours calculator provided the correct format so I cheated lol
But thanks again!  I don't have enough clout here yet to upvote you but I tried, and it said it was recorded as feedback
